# Search last 7 days in facebook search api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I need a solution in graph api or fql to search a specific keyword for last 7 days or a way to count the no of total search results.

Right now,

I am applying a heavy limit. It works if result is single page, but fails on pagination.

http://graph.facebook.com/search?type=post&q=wonders&since=2012-01-13&limit=99999999999999

I want to gather data for statisticall purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pagination issue is a current bug listed http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Per Jashwant's comments below, he has found that the API limits 500 per request and there's no way around this designed limitation.

Comment: I know paging has issues, but I want to know if there are ways ( which I am able to think ) to search api data for few days ?

I can only think of requesting data by following nextpage link again and again . But that will take a lot of time. 

Any help ?

Comment: @ DMCS Do you really think your reply is answer to this question ?

To add to the question, 
If I had a greater limit like 999999999, it only fetches data around 500. (497, 492, 495 etc) i.e. facebook puts a limit of 500 on it.

I cannot fetch more than 500. I dont think this approach is going to work.
60 requests, 19 minutes, but still not able to fetch a complete 1 day data :(

Comment: When something is a bug, that is the answer.

Comment: I've marked it as answer but please edit it and show the relevant info.
Like 500 is the limit for one request. And there's no way trick to fetch a large data like 1 day.